# Evaluating $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{({2}^{n})(n-1)(n!)}{(2n)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the sum of this series:
> $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{({2}^{n})(n-1)(n!)}{(2n)!}$$

I tried to make use of the series $\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$ putting $x=\sqrt2$, and writing $2^{n}$ as $(\sqrt2)^{2n}$. But $(n-1)(n!)$ was giving me troubles.

Then I tried to turn it into a telescopic series by writing $n-1$ as a difference of $2$ terms but it didn't work either.

Anything would help.

Comment: Do you really mean to write $x!$ and $(2x)!$, or should it be $n!$ and $(2n)!$ ?

Comment: I meant to use 'n', thanks for pointing out.

Comment: One way is proving [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B2%5En%28n-1%29n%21%2F%282n%29%21%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cm-1%7D%5D%20) (by induction...)

Comment: You might get somewhere starting with$$f(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n-1}{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)\cdots(n+2)(n+1)} x^{2n}$$and differentiating $k$ times to eliminate the terms in the denominator. When $k=n$ you end up with $f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}$.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the answers, although I didn't understand anything because I am in high school.

I found an easier solution:

$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{(2^n)((2n-1)-(1))(n)!}{(2n)!}$  = $\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{(2^{n-1})(n-1)!}{(2n-2)!}-\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{(2^n)(n)!}{(2n)!})$

This turns into a beutiful telescopic and results in $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{2!}) = \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 4):

$$S=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n(n-1)(n!)}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n(n-1)(n-2)!(n!)}{(2n)!(n-2)!}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+1)(n-2)!}$$
$$=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n}{(n-2)!}B(n;n+1)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n}{(n-2)!}\int_0^1(1-x)^nx^{n-1}dx$$
$$=4\int_0^1(1-x)^2x\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n(1-x)^nx^n}{n!} \right)dx$$
$$=4\int_0^1(1-x)^2xe^{2x(1-x)}dx=4\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\,\bigg|_{\alpha=2}\int_0^1(1-x)e^{\alpha x(1-x)}dx$$
Making the substitution $t=1-x$
$$S=4\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\,\bigg|_{\alpha=2}\int_0^1xe^{\alpha x(1-x)}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,S=2\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\,\bigg|_{\alpha=2}\int_0^1e^{\alpha x(1-x)}dx\overset{x=\frac12-\frac t2}{=}\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\,\bigg|_{\alpha=2}\int_0^1e^{\frac\alpha4 (1-t^2)}dt$$
$$=2\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\,\bigg|_{\alpha=2}\frac{e^\frac\alpha4}{\sqrt\alpha}\int_0^{\sqrt\alpha} e^{-\frac{x^2}4}dx$$
$$=\left(\frac12\frac{e^\frac\alpha4}{\sqrt\alpha}-\frac{e^\frac\alpha4}{(\sqrt\alpha)^3}\right)\int_0^{\sqrt\alpha} e^{-\frac{x^2}4}dx\,\bigg|_{\alpha=2}+\frac1\alpha\,\bigg|_{\alpha=2}=\frac12$$

Comment: I was making similar transformations up till the point you took the $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}$. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

*Probably too complicated but wrote for your curiosity*

If you are familiar with some series expansions, you could notice that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n n! }{(2 n)!}x^{2 n}=\frac{1}{8} x \left(\sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}
   \left(x^2+2\right) \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+2
   x\right)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ n! }{(2 n)!}x^{2 n}=1+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{x^2}{4}} x\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Subtracting and removing the terms corresponding to $n=0$ and $n=1$

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(n-1) n!}{(2 n)!}x^{2 n}=\frac{1}{8} x \left(\sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}
   \left(x^2-2\right) \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+2
   x\right)$$

Now, using $x=\sqrt 2$, then the result.